# How to install Apple's Game Center app on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

How do I get Game Center app on my iPad Wi-Fi?

I am unable to find the app on the device as well as the App Store.

Comment: Please edit the question and specify the version of iOS running on your iPad.

Answer (score 2):

The Game Center application has been removed from iOS 10, but you can still manage your Game Center settings from the Settings.app
On your iPad tap Settings > Game Center.

Answer (score 1):

The standalone Game Center app was removed from iOS 10 and macOS Sierra.

However the service continues to remain available.

You can log into Game Center on your iOS device by going to `Settings app → Game Center`.

On earlier versions of iOS (like iOS 9) the app is installed by default.